# How is $\mathbb R \to S^1$ nullhomotopic?

Tags: algebraic-topology, intuition

Every map $\mathbb R \to S^1$ is nullhomotopic.

The covering map $p: \mathbb R \to S^1$ is given by $p(x)=\cos(2\pi x, \sin 2\pi x)$.

**How is this map null-homotopic if we are wrapping $\mathbb R$ infinitely many times around the circle?**

Comment: Well, do you understand the proof that it's null-homotopic?

Comment: The proof will be not so different from how you prove that every map $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is null-homotopic. So, it will be helpful to ponder about how it is possible that the map $f(x)=x$ can be shrunken into a point if it covers the entire real line.

Comment: The wrap count is only relevant when the domain is $S^1$ or, in other words, $[0,1]$ with the endpoints identified. When the domain is $\Bbb{R}$ there is nothing constraining the images of two points (typically $0$ and $1$) *simultaneously*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $X$ is contractible and let $f: X \to Y$ be any continuous map into any space $Y$. Since $X$ is contractible then $Id_X \simeq c_{x_0}$ where $c_{x_0}: X \to X$ is the map sending everything to $x_0$. So,
$$f=f \circ Id_X \simeq f \circ c_{x_0} = c_{f(x_0)}.$$
So, $f$ is null-homotopic.

Conversely, if any $f: X \to Y$ is null-homotopic for any $Y$, then let $Y=X$ and let $f=Id_X$. Then, $Id_X$ is null-homotopic and thus $X$ is contractible.

---

We can also show $Y$ is contractible iff every $f: X \to Y$ is null-homotopic for any $X$.

Comment: Did you mean to say that $X$ is contractible iff $f : X \to Y$ is nullhomotopic for any $Y$?

Comment: @GuidoA. No. A space is contractible iff every map out of the space, or every map into the space, is null-homotopic.

Comment: Agreed, but the circle is not contractible so I'd argue that the equivalent statement for maps out of the contractible space is more relevant.

Comment: @GuidoA. Yea. The part under the line I just added for completion. It's not needed for this post though. But every map $S^1 \to \mathbb R$ is null-homotopic too. That's what the last part I wrote is saying.

Answer (score 6):

For a fixed parameter $t$ consider the map $\mathbb{R} \to S^1$ given by
$$
p_t(x) = (\cos(2\pi t x), \sin(2 \pi t x)).
$$
Then $p_1$ is your map, and $p_0$ is the constant map sending everything to $(1, 0)$.

Comment: I don't see the significance of this.

Comment: @TomislavOstojich, it's a null-homotopy of the OP's map. It's an exact answer to the question.

Comment: No, I mean, I don't see the significance of you taking the same map and adding a variable to it. All you did was show that OP's map belongs to a family that has a constant map as a brother. So what?

Comment: @TomislavOstojich Did you, perhaps not notice that the function $p(t,x)=p_t(x)$ is continuous from $[0,1]\times\Bbb{R}$ to $S^1$, and therefore a homotopy between $p_0$ and $p_1$?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen no

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**  $\Bbb R$ is contractible.

Answer (score 2):

Lets's prove something more general. Take $X$ a contractible space with a homotopy equivalence $H : 1_X \simeq c_{x_0}$, and let $f : X \to Y$ be a continuous map. Now, the function

$$
\begin{align}
L : \ &I \times X \to Y \\
& (t,x) \mapsto f(H(t,x))
\end{align}
$$

is continuous, and $L_0(x) = f(H_0(x)) = f(x)$, $L_1(x) = f(H_1(x)) = f(x_0)$. Hence $f$ is homotopy equivalent to the constant function $f(x_0)$. We have thus proven:

> **Proposition.** Let $X$ be a contractible space. Then, any continuous function $f : X \to Y$ is nullhomotopic.

And of course, since $\mathbb{R}$ is contractible, this solves your problem.

Even if we map into the circle making an infinite amount of 'wrapping', any path $[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ we choose maps to a path which we are able to contract. This is weaker than being able to do the same with the whole line, which (I think) is were your misconception stems from. Also, note that this has to do with the flexibility of contractions being able to move all points (which is not allowed when talking about elements of a certain fundamental group).